# Access child host elements nativeElement properties from host element in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

I want to the elementReference of mat-card from parent component i.e AppComponent. I have written a directive and attached it to the host component. If I try to access elem.nativeElement.childNodes[0] , it gives undefined. How to access mat-card element reference from the parent component.

Here's the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4-elemref). 
Thanks 
Here's my directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[displayStyle]' })
export class DisplayStyleDirective {
constructor(elem: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer2) {
   console.log(elem.nativeElement.childNodes[0])
   }
 }
```

In console i get undefined .

App.Component.html

```
<div>
  <h3>Recognized Images</h3>
  <div>
    <card-overview-example displayStyle *ngFor="let user of existingUserInfo" [User]="user"></card-overview-example>
  </div> 
</div>
```

App.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  AfterViewInit,
  ElementRef,
  Renderer2,
  ViewChild
} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2) { }
  ngOnInit() { }
existingUserInfo:Array<userDetails> = [
  {userID:"121",filename:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/Angular_full_color_logo.svg/250px-Angular_full_color_logo.svg.png"},
  {userID:"122",filename:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/Angular_full_color_logo.svg/250px-Angular_full_color_logo.svg.png"},
  {userID:"123",filename:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/Angular_full_color_logo.svg/250px-Angular_full_color_logo.svg.png"}
]

 ngAfterViewInit() {
  }



}

export interface userDetails {
  userID: string;
  filename: string;
}
```

Card-overview-example.html

```
<mat-card class="example-card">
  <img [src]="userDetails.filename" alt="Photo of {{userDetails.userID}}">
  <p >{{userDetails.userID}}</p>
</mat-card>
```

card-overview-example.ts

```
import {Component,Input} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic cards
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'card-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'card-overview-example.html'
})
export class CardOverviewExample {
    @Input("User") userDetails: userDetails;
}

export interface userDetails {
  userID: string;
  filename: string;
}
```

Here's the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4-elemref).

Answer (score 0):

Try `elem.nativeElement.children[0]` instead of `elem.nativeElement.childNodes[0]`

Comment: You should be using ViewChild to access the directive

Comment: elem.nativeElement.children didnt work . Still its undefined

Comment: Any links on how to use ViewChild to access directive ? @DavidAnthonyAcosta

Comment: I'm getting my directive as Object with no keys if i use 
viewChild@ViewChild(DisplayStyleDirective) ds : DisplayStyleDirective and in my ngAfterViewInit() {
   console.log(this.ds)
  }

Comment: I want to apply styles to mat-card . I have re-used the same component and in one place i want the styles to be added and in another place i dont want. That's why i thought of taking the elementRef and apply styles to it .

Comment: Why don't you use `[ngClass]` directive?